# How to convert ANSI byte to Unicode string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, atl

I have an `vector<BYTE>` that represents characters in a string.  I want to interpret those characters as ASCII characters and store them in a Unicode (UTF-16) string.  The current code assumes that the characters in the `vector<BYTE>` are Unicode rather than ASCII.  This works fine for standard ASCII, but fails for extended ASCII characters.  These characters need to be interpreted using the current code page retrieved via `GetACP()`. How would I go about creating a Unicode (UTF-16) string with these ASCII characters?

EDIT: I believe the solution should have something to do with the macros discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.80).aspx  I'm just not exactly sure how the actual implementation would go.

```
int ExtractByteArray(CATLString* pszResult, const CByteVector* pabData)
{
    // place the data into the output cstring
    pszResult->Empty();
    for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < pabData->GetSize(); iIndex++)
        *pszResult += (TCHAR)pabData->GetAt(iIndex);

    return RC_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you are using MFC, can't you get `CString` to do it automatically?

Comment: *"I have an `vector<BYTE>` that represents characters in a string."* - why not `std::string` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "extended ASCII".  There _are_ quite a few different 8 bit single byte encodings which are identical with ASCII for their first 128 code points, but they're not ASCII (and there are quite a few of them).

Comment: Here are the `CString` constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cws1zdt8(v=vs.110).aspx  Just use the one that receives a pointer to `char` and a length, and your job is done.

Comment: @LihO The data is returned from a device in this generic way.  It is then interpreted based on a set of given criteria.  The data could be an integer, bitmap, string, etc.

Comment: @bgh10788: Then I don't see any sense in converting binary data of bitmap into any kind of string (UTF-16 or not).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This doesn't seem to work.  I get the dreaded box/question mark when the byte value is > 128.  Plus, `CByteVector` is implemented in such a way that I cannot get a pointer to the first object, just the value.

Comment: Well, I don't think that `CString` is broken. But I'm confused. In the question you said you had `vector<BYTE>`. I've no enthusiasm to help if we can't even work out what the question is.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [MultibyteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) to convert that string to unicode

Comment: Well you could do this but it's easier to use the appropriate `CString` constructor and let it convert.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Of course it is better but it only work for `MFC` and `ATL` applications(I guess it solve the problem for the `bgh10788`) but this function work for any program and framework on `Windows`

Comment: But the question tags MFC and names `CATLString`, so such a solution would seem appropriate.

Comment: ASCII characters are 1 byte, the unicode is 2 bytes. Therefore multibytetowidechar is not the right function - ASCII is not multibyte to begin with!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a `vector<BYTE>` that represents characters in a string. I want to interpret those characters as ASCII characters and store them in a Unicode (UTF-16) string

You should use `std::vector<BYTE>` only when you are working with binary data. While working with strings use `std::string` instead. Note that this `std::string` object will contain special characters that will be encoded by sequences of one or more bytes (thus called **multi-byte** characters), but these are not [ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z4t9ed1(v=vs.71).aspx) characters.

Once you use `std::string`, you can use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) to create own function that will convert a `std::string` (which contains multi-byte UTF-8 characters) into `std::wstring` containing UTF-16 encoded points:

```
// multi byte to wide char:
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
```

Comment: But I am working with binary data. The point of this function is to take this binary data and convert it to a CATLString.

Comment: @bgh10788: Why would you convert binary data into string? That makes no sense. If it's binary data, then treat it as binary data. If it's a string then treat it as one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MFC, let `CString` do the job.